# Inno Setup - #define directive - how to use previously defined variable?

Tags: inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup version 5.4.2.

I want to define the path for the files to copy (the Source: parameter in the [Files] section as two parts, a base path and sub-directory names, that I use for special files (like .dlls).
I have tried the following:

```
#define MyAppSetupDir "D:\MyApp\setup"
#define MyAppSetupQtDLLs {#MyAppSetupDir}"\DLLs"
[Files]
Source: {#MyAppSetupDir}\MyApp.exe; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: {#MyAppSetupDLLs}\mstext35.dll; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
```

but I get the following compilation error

```
[ISPP] Expression expected but opening brace ("{") found.
```

I also tried to enclose the braces in "", like

```
#define MyAppSetupQtDLLs "{#MyAppSetupDir}\DLLs"
```

But this time I got

```
Error: Source file "D:\MyApp\setup\{#MyAppSetupDir}\DLLs\mstext35.dll" does not exist.
```

So, ISSP is correctly replacing the MyAppSetupDir variable, but then puts again the simple text, as if it did not recognize the directive.

I have searched everywhere, and I already found a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043960/how-to-set-ispp-defines-based-on-default-inno-setup-variables) about using the `{commonappdata}`, but I could not find how to do this, neither in the documentation nor in the KB.
I would really appreciate some hints, as it looks I am close, but not finding the right solution..

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
#define MyAppSetupDir "D:\MyApp\setup"
#define MyAppSetupQtDLLs MyAppSetupDir + "\DLLs"
```